Error when building with xcode on Azure Pipelines
I'm trying to implement CI/CD for my team's Flutter app, and when using Xcode@5 task to build an IOS version of the app, im getting the following output:
Starting: Xcode Build

==============================================================================

Task         : Xcode

Description  : Build, test, or archive an Xcode workspace on macOS. Optionally package an app.

Version      : 5.248.1

Author       : Microsoft Corporation

Help         : 

==============================================================================

##[error]TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trim')

Finishing: Xcode Build

Ive been trying to solve this in multiple ways for quite some time now without success, nobody else on the team was able to solve it. This is the Xcode task in question:
- task: Xcode@5
            displayName: "Xcode Build"
            inputs:
              actions: 'clean archive'
              packageApp: true
              signingOption: 'manual'
              signingIdentity: $(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)
              provisioningProfileUuid: $(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)
              teamId: $(APPLE_TEAM_ID)
              sdk: 'iphoneos'
              scheme: 'Runner'
              destinationPlatformOption: 'iOS'
              destinationTypeOption: 'devices'
              configuration: 'Release'
              xcWorkspacePath: 'ios/Runner.xcworkspace'
              exportMethod: 'app-store'
              exportTeamId: $(APPLE_TEAM_ID)
              archivePath: 'ios/archive/Runner.xcarchive'
              exportPath: 'output/iphoneos/Release'
              xcodeVersion: 'specifyPath'
              xcodeDeveloperDir: '/Applications/Xcode_$(XCODE_VERSION).app/Contents/Developer'
              args: '-verbose'
            continueOnError: false

I`d appreciate if anyone could help.

Try running the pipeline in debug mode. Double-check if all pipeline variables $(xxx) are expanded/resolved correctly.

@RuiJarimba thanks. The debug mode helped, now i'm experiencing a new issue with error code 65, but my signing certificate and provisioning profile seems to be ok.
